# .htaccess to have index.php and assets inside a public folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, wamp

I want to have my project tree divided like this:

- application
- public

  - assets
  - index.php
- system

Should I have two `.htaccess` files (one inside the **root** and another inside `/public`) or just one?

My project is in the URL http://localhost/my-project/

I have already pointed `$system_path` and `$application_path` to their parent folder, like this:

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
```

But I might be missing something.

Comment: Are application and system folder within the Apache web directory? Do they need to be?

Comment: Yes, they are. The path is `C:\wamp\www\my-project\`.
I would like them to stay there because of how I'm organizing my git repository for this project.

Comment: But do you have `C:\wamp\www\my-project` set as your `DocumentRoot` in Apache?  The reason I ask is that unless you have anything in `application` and `system` that need to be directly accessed by a web client, you should simply define the `DocumentRoot` as `C:\wamp\www\my-project\public` then you have better protected your underlying application logic from prying eyes and also rendered your question moot. You could easily still have your repository rooted at `my-project` (no need for a change there).

Comment: Okay, but wouldn't that imply that I wouldn't be able to have different projects inside of this apache server? (I'm guessing we would then be talking virtual hosts)

Comment: This wouldn't apply anything like that. If you had other projects on the server, you would likely just configure virtual hosts for them, with the appropriate `DocumentRoot `for where the publicly available resources are for each project.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one `.htaccess` file on your **root** directory, with following entry:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Just tried that, now I'm getting a 500 error... according to the Apache log:

`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.`

Comment: @LeandroDimitrio use it : `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$`