# Links outside folder 404

Tags: html, .htaccess, routes

I'm making a basic project and it has the following directory structure:

```
|-app
|-bin
|-pages
|-pub
|-var
|-vendor
```

I've set my vhost `DocumentRoot` to /var/www/project/pub and inside pub has an index.php file. Restarting `apache` service and navigating to the project in-browser shows what I'm expecting.

However the problem lies with this code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/pages/supplier">
            Supplier Module
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/pages/socket">
            Sockets (basic chat)
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

PHPStorm shows no path error or anything and I can see my index.php inside these folders:

```
|-pages
|-----socket
|---------index.php
|-----supplier
|---------index.php
```

yet it returns a 404 error. What is wrong with my code, everything (to me) seems perfectly valid.. even if I change the link to:

```
/pages/<area>/index.php
```

it still returns a 404 error - I thought `/` in Frontend world means DOCUMENT_ROOT? What's missing from my code?

### edit

I tried searching around, I think it may be due to lack of .htaccess configuration. I found a SO post: [.htaccess to have index.php and assets inside a public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705770/htaccess-to-have-index-php-and-assets-inside-a-public-folder) and tried the answer. I added .htaccess to my root with contents:

```
Options All -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pub/index.php/$1 [L]
```

but this seemed to have no affect..

Comment: Are you not targeting files in your hrefs? The target your are trying to reach cannot be found. `PathToFile/SubFolder` doesn't direct you to any file in the folder. You need to `/PathToFile/SubFolder/File.html` for this to work. Be aware that the hrefs are casesensitive!

Comment: You have also already specified your root folder. Therefore you doesn't need to specify the startpage with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pub/...` instead use: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: @SimonJensen That's not correct. hrefs dosnt doesn't need a specific target. `href="/pages/supplier"` will open the index.php file in the supplier folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move pages folder inside pub folder.

To clarify: The browser can not access content thats in a parent or sibling folder of your document root. And in frontend world `/` means `/pub/` in your filesystem.

Comment: but semantically - shoud pages be inside there? To me should be outside of pub/ ?

Comment: You declared pub the document root wich means that when you access it from a browser, pub folder is the root. So when you say `href="/pages/"` it means `/pub/pages/` in your filesystem. Do you a framework?

Comment: `Do you a framework?` - as in? bascially I'm building a framework so would prefer it to eventually references as `/area/page.php`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Just curious here, is your project to create a framework? If no, then you should consider using an existing framwork like Laravel.

Comment: I would opt for Symfony personally but I'm making a MVC-styled OOP framework to introduce people to a few concepts before being able to jump into MVC :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Alright. You will have to write a router as the browser cant access the files directly.